# Agregando una pagina de inicio con django

Tags: python, django

tengo mi aplicación en django y quiero agregarle una página nuevo llamada homepage.html entonces en mi proyecto llamado web en el views.py agregué:

```
def homepage(request):
        return render_to_response('homepage.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Seguidamente en web/urls.py agregué mi url

```
url(r'^web.views.homepage/', name="homepage"),
```

Ahora en mi aplicación llamada crud tengo mi directorio templates dentro de el otra carpeta llamada crud (asi vi un tutorial que decía que así era mejor) y en este directorio mi homepage.html el cual no puse nada solo un texto de ejemplo por ahora

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Bienvenido {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h3> Bienvenido , esta es una pagina de inicio </h3>
{% endblock %}
```

La cosa es que a la hora de levantar el servidor me dice

```
url(r'^web.views.homepage/', name="homepage"),
TypeError: url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'view'
```

¿Me salté algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu URL te falta definir la vista que consume la misma:

```
url(r'^web.views.homepage/', [tu_vista.tu_funcion], name="homepage"),
```

la cual en tu caso sería:

```
url(r'^web.views.homepage/', views.homepage, name="homepage"),
```

Saludos.

Comment: oye uchisimas gracias jajajjaja cierto! lo siento por la pregunta tan tonta :( bueno no se me olvidara mas jaja ya correo mi servidor :D ahora se supone que para acceder a esta deberia ser localhost:8000/homepage ???? es que ahora estoy viendo como pongo esa pagina por default al abrir localhost:8000 porque me abre "crud"

Comment: haha de nada. Ahora entendiendo tu proyecto, parece que "crud" es tu app vdd? y esa url la declaraste en crud/url.py por lo que la debe reconocer en la direccion localhost:8000/crud/homepage/, cierto? si lo que quieres es que sea en localhost:8000/homepage/ debes declarar la url en el archivo url.py del proyecto, el mismo que se encuentra en la ruta de settings.py. Saludos. PD: no olvides marcar como correcta la respuesta.

Comment: esa url la declare en la carpeta del proyecto (web), no de la aplicacion (crud) asi que deberia poder acceder cuando pongo localhost:8000/homepage aunque ciertamente el homepage.html esta dentro de la carpeta templates de la aplicacion (crud)

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo poner en el archivo **urls.py** de tu proyecto:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('<nombre_del_app>.urls', namespace='<nombre_del_app>')),
]
```

luego en tu app (crud) crear un archivo **urls.py** con lo siguiente:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.homepage, name = 'home'),
    # El resto de tus urls con sus respectivas vistas
    # ...
]
```

Y en tu **views.py** te recomiendo tener algo así:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render

def homepage(request):
    # El template debe estar en templates/<nombre_del_app>/<nombre_del_template>.html
    # El template base debe estar en templates/base.html
    template = loader.get_template('<nombre_del_app(crud en este caso)>/homepage.html')
    # El contexto es lo que se va a enviar al template
    # puedes enviar variables y usarlas en el template
    # por ejemplo puedes enviar un Modelo
    context = {}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: de antemano gracias por la respuesta, me arrojo el error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Comment: En que archivo se está dando el error?, Y debería solucionarse poniendo el nombre de la app, no poniendo 'app'.

Comment: ciertamente amigo si, culpa mia , una pregunta porque se usa namespace en vez de name? ah bueno si cambie app por crud jajja sorry pero iguamente sigo sin poder ingresar a esa pagina creada al colocar http://localhost:8000/crud/templates/crud/homepage.html que se supone que es la jerarquia donde esta mi homepage.html  y en view.py de la aplicacion (crud) puse template = loader.get_template('crud/templates/crud/homepage.html')

Comment: No debes porner la jerarquía del template, simplemente pon la URL que asignaste a la vista en el urlpatterns, es decir en este caso localhost:8000, la ubicación del template se pone en la variable template de la vista que se ejecuta al entrar en una url.

Comment: subi de jerarquia mis html y nada , te dejo el codigo a ver si es que no ves algo , yo sigo revisando a ver , si puedes claro jeje  https://www.dropbox.com/s/cayf5gigxbbowv8/web.rar?dl=0